# How do I compare unix time stamps (numbers) inside a function in PHP?

Tags: php, function, timestamp

Ok, I fear that this is just me having forgotten some small stupid thing about PHP, but I just can't seem to figure out what is going on here.

#### Test code:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$closingDate     = mktime(23, 59, 59, 3, 27, 2009);

function f1()
{
    return time() > $closingDate;
}
function f2()
{
    return time() < $closingDate;
}

printf('    Time: %u
Closing: %u

t > c: %u
f1   : %u

t < c: %u
f2   : %u', 
    time(), 
    $closingDate, 
    time() > $closingDate,
    f1(), 
    time() < $closingDate,
    f2());
```

The problem is that the output doesn't make sense to me at all. And I don't get why it turns out like it does:

```
Time: 1235770914
Closing: 1238194799

t > c: 0
f1   : 1

t < c: 1
f2   : 0
```

Why doesn't the function output the same result as the code inside the function?? What am I not getting here? Have I looked myself completely blind on my own code? What is going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not passing `$closingDate` to the functions. They are comparing `time` against `null`.

Try:

```
function f1()
{
    global $closingDate;
    return time() > $closingDate;
}
function f2()
{
    global $closingDate;
    return time() < $closingDate;
}
```

Or:

```
// call with f1($closingDate);
function f1($closingDate)
{
    return time() > $closingDate;
}

// call with f2($closingDate);
function f2($closingDate)
{
    return time() < $closingDate;
}
```

Check out the PHP documentation on [variable scoping](http://us.php.net/global).

Comment: knew there was something stupid I had forgotten :p too long since I have programmed PHP... thank you =) This fixed it: global $closingDate;

Comment: It would probably be better practice to pass $closingDate as a parameter to the functions instead of using the global keyword.  So your declaration would be: function f1($closingDate).  If you were to modify the value it could lead to unexpected results in when other functions try to access it.